# Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined in react 17, webpack 5 while making api calls through actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Having this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` when trying to make a api call using superagent.

Currently i am using react 17, webpack 5 along with css modules and all latest packages.

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^6.0.10",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^3.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules",
      {
        webpackHotModuleReloading: true,
        autoResolveMultipleImports: true,
        filetypes: {
          ".scss": {
            syntax: "postcss-scss",
          },
        },
        generateScopedName:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
            ? "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            : "[hash:base64:5]",
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          isDev ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                auto: (resourcePath) =>
                  resourcePath.indexOf("assets/stylesheets") === -1,
                localIdentName: isDev
                  ? "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                  : "[hash:base64:5]",
              },
              sourceMap: isDev,
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Babel 7, install these two dependencies:

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

And, in .babelrc, add:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
    ]
}
```